# Tag deletion request: [buttons]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are only two questions tagged with [buttons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons): [one question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12813/what-does-exit-mean) is actually asking about the function of a button, while [the other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43732/how-can-you-free-yourself-from-a-grab-in-ssbb) is simply asking how to do something.  The first question, while being relevant to the tag, could be covered simply enough with just the game tag.  The second question loses absolutely nothing by having the tag removed.  I propose it be nuked from existence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my super awesome editing powers I destroyed the evil menace of the [buttons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons) tag.

Comment: I've destroyed a couple tags that were only on one question, but there were *two* questions tagged with this.  I was scared :(

Comment: @DaveMcClelland you don't need to worry about one-off tags, they'll die on their own eventually

Comment: That's what I had though, but some of the questions were pretty old.  How often do those tags get pruned?